# Jenkins fails during parsing poms

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have problems with one job on my Jenkins server.
It fails during pom parse with this message:

```
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
[workspace] $ java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp /opt/edb/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/opt/apache/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/apache/maven3 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.17.jar /opt/edb/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 55430
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [java, -Xmx512m, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -cp, /opt/edb/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/opt/apache/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar, org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main, /opt/apache/maven3, /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.17.jar, /opt/edb/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar, 55430] failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:673)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.<init>(ProcessCache.java:112)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:231)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:704)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1516)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Failed to deserialize the Callable object.
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1997078527, Size: 0
```

I have tried creating a new build, no luck
Building locally works fine
All other similar jobs work fine

I'm running letest jenkins (1.489)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hard disk is full.
Try to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the workspace is corrupted and on your pom.xml is not readable. Have to try to clean the workspace for this specific job ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed for me by setting the correct version Java version in the PATH (as required in the pom.xml) - See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5519