# Jenkins Build Failure. ERROR: Failed to parse POMs

Tags: java, maven, jar, jenkins, pom.xml

Hi I'm having this problem with `Jenkins` when trying to use it with a maven build project.
This is the error log.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I looked through older questions and none of them seem to answer my problem. I'm not using a repo, just local.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Test3/workspace
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
[SmartAssetScreenShotTool copy] $ /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.5.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.43.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 64622
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java, -cp, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.5.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/apache-maven-3.2.2, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.43.jar, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar, 64622] failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:748)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:160)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:843)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1833)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1730)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1627)
    at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:263)
    at hudson.util.ColorPalette.<clinit>(ColorPalette.java:39)
    at hudson.model.BallColor.<clinit>(BallColor.java:56)
    at hudson.model.Result.<clinit>(Result.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor44.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:929)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1873)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Someone else asked about the same error message on StackOverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251236/jenkins-fails-during-parsing-poms

Comment: `a.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.` Did you check out the permissions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Jenkins. How do I check permissions?

Comment: @Ray Toal Thanks for the response but that question doesn't have an adequate resolution.

Comment: Sorry.  BTW, did you figure out the possible meaning for the key line in your stack trace, namely "Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions."?

Comment: It's cool. No, I don't know what to do with that. I'm hoping someone else had that issue before and was able to resolve it.

Comment: Found the answer. This solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519884/jenkins-cant-connect-to-window-server-not-enough-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer a while back. Please refer to this for those who may need the solution in the future [Jenkins can't connect to window server - not enough permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519884/jenkins-cant-connect-to-window-server-not-enough-permissions)